# dynamic resource with kendo scheduler

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I would to update a resource at runtime in the Telerik Scheduler widget.

I use this simple code to modify a well configured widget:

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data('kendoScheduler');
var resourceDatasource = scheduler.resources[0].dataSource;
resourceDatasource.add({ text: "Meeting Room 201", value: 2, color: "#f58a8a" });
scheduler.refresh();
```

output :

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'c._continuousEvents')
```

[Here a code](http://dojo.telerik.com/IcAZu) that I edited from official guide

Answer (score 2):

I solved, instead of

```
scheduler.refresh();
```

use

```
scheduler.view(scheduler.view().name);
```